# How to add multiple nested dictionaries at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have a method which requires being able to add multiple nested dictionaries at once.

For example:

```py
mydict = {}
mydict['subdict']['subdict2'] = {'this': 'is what i want'}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(dict)
mydict['subdict']['subdict2'] = {'this': 'is what i want'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an empty dict inside the dict in order to have nested dict.

Here;

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict["nested_item_1"] = {}
my_dict["nested_item_1"] = your_variable_here
```